# Create method with params ref T parameter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is what I've got in a project including fairly complex cases of reflection:

```
static int PopulateValues<T>(List<string> propertyNames, ref T list) { /*...*/ }

// Example call:
PopulateValues(propertyNames, ref list1);
```

I'd really like to add `params` along and do `params ref T[] lists` to allow usage:

```
PopulateValues(propertyNames, ref list1, ref list2, ...);
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> Parameter cannot have both 'params' and 'ref' modifiers.

My initial thought was letting `list` be an `object[]`, but the usage would be ugly (casting `object`). So for now, I'm calling the method one time for each type, doing unnecessary multiple enumerations.

**SOLVED:** I don't need `ref` for calling reflection methods on parameter class (`SetValue`, `GetValue`, `InvokeMember` etc), which means that I can skip the `ref` altogether. Really, I should have tried that.

Comment: what is contained in list1 and list2?

Comment: Are you really sure you need that 'ref' keyword? If it's a class then you can modify the properties of that object without changing the reference to that object.

Comment: Can you describe your actual problem a bit more? What are you doing with those list parameters? And what are you passing in? Fields or local variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### On `ref` + `params`:

A member can't be a reference. And since `params` transforms each parameter into array member this isn't possible.

The only thing I can think of is manually creating a number of overloads.

---

But in your case I don't see why you need `ref` in the first place. To add members to a list you don't need to change the reference itself, and thus don't need to pass it my ref in the first place.

Comment: This was correct, I do not need `ref` in order to do changing reflection on parameters

Answer (score 1):

`params` is actually an array; so just make it an array parameter (`T[]`, no `ref`) and simply change the values before returning. This is the closest you'll manage in tw general case. Example:

```
Foo[] values =....
SomeMethod(values);
// now look at values[n] etc
```

Comment: The `Foo` class in you example, could be `Bar` for method parameter 3

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with C#'s syntax. Furthermore, I can't imagine how that would work. You get your array, but then setting an item in it would set the reference value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some interesting solution:

```
public delegate RecursionRefFunc<T> RecursionRefFunc<T>(ref T arg);

public static RecursionRefFunc<T> Boo<T>(ref T input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input); // Work in here
    return Boo;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3, x4 = 4, x5 = 5;
    Boo(ref x1)(ref x2)(ref x3)(ref x4)(ref x5);
}

// Output: //
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

Delegate can declare in recursion.

Return a function outside and call again.

<s>And you will be killed by the code reviewer.</s>

---

Advertisement OW<: [CWKSC/MyLib_Csharp](https://github.com/CWKSC/MyLib_Csharp)

---

It is copy form another question:

[c# - Interesting "params of ref" feature, any workarounds? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975384/11693034)