# How to pass ref parameters in params

Tags: c#, parameters, ref

I want to pass `n` number of parameters to a method (both reference and normal).
Here is my source code

```
static void testParams(params object[] parameters) 
  { 
      for (int index = 0; index < parameters.Length; index++) 
        {
           Console.WriteLine(parameters[index ].gettype();
        }
  }
```

Its working fine when I used as

```
int i=0, j=0; 
double k=0.0;
testParams(i,j,k)
```

but i want it like,

```
int i=0, j=0; 
double k=0.0;
testParams(i,j,ref k)
```

How to do this, please help me...

Comment: Short answer is you can't. What are you trying to accomplish with this? there is nothing in the code you provided which suggests you need a `ref` parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interesting "params of ref" feature, any workarounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776020/interesting-params-of-ref-feature-any-workarounds)

Comment: @p.s.w.g : It is just a sample code. I need to pass the parameters to a legacy dll probably built in `LAB VIEW`

Comment: @shf301 : No.. its not. Thank you

Comment: @Pramodh Perhaps you can post some more information about the actual method you're trying to call. There may be a different way do what you need.

Comment: @Pramodh You also can try make a C funtion like testParams(char* x,...); then use c# to call it[DLLImport("your dll")].but i am not sure that is can be

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. If you want to pass a parameter by reference, the method should have a ref in its definition.

For example

```
static void Mymethod(ref int i)
```

can be called by

```
int localvariable = 5;
Mymethod(ref localvariable);
```

but your method definition cannot be

```
static void Mymethod(int i)
```