# Pass infinite params by reference (using keywords params and ref together)

Tags: c#, object, reference, .net-4.0, params-keyword

Is it possible to pass an infinite number of parameters into my function by reference?

I know this is not valid, but is there a way to do this?

```
private bool Test(ref params object[] differentStructures)
{
    //Change array here and reflect changes per ref
}

TestStructOne test1 = default(TestStructOne);
TestStructTwo test2 = default(TestStructTwo);
TestStructOne test3 = default(TestStructOne);
if (Test(test1, test2, test3)) { //happy dance }
```

I know I could do the following, but I'm hoping to eliminate having to create an extra variable to contain all the objects...

```
private bool Test(ref object[] differentStructures)
{
    //Change array here and reflect changes per ref
}

TestStructOne test1 = default(TestStructOne);
TestStructTwo test2 = default(TestStructTwo);
TestStructOne test3 = default(TestStructOne);
object[] tests = new object[] { test1, test2, test3 };
if (Test(ref tests)) { //simi quazi happy dance }
```

Comment: Nope, you can't have an array of references in C#.

Comment: Ok...  I JUST clicked the "Post Your Question" button...  Didn't even have time for my browser to refresh and this comment was posted.

Comment: I am not sure if this is duplicate but similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776020/interesting-params-of-ref-feature-any-workarounds

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Well, you can have an array of references. But you can't have an array of reference parameters :)

Comment: Why not just pass in `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Note that in your second example you don't need the `ref` to mutate the individual objects, or to assign new objects to the array.  You only need it if you want to assign a new array to `tests`. And it will not allow you to change the reference that `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` point at either way. Maybe you should tell us what you plan to do with the array inside of `Test`.

Comment: @JonSkeet whoops, I didn't even notice how foolish my comment is :)

Comment: @juharr that explains a lot...  +1 Thanks for that side note, I never knew that to be honest (though I have used it like that before many times).  Because of your comment my code will forevermore be cleaner.  Thanks!  My intent was to take a bunch of objects in and write them to a byte array.

Comment: @leppie, please quit trying to edit the question's tags...  I put .Net4 on there for a reason.  I want to make sure this is all in the realm of .Net4 ..  There are other frameworks out there that could yield different responses.

Comment: @ArvoBowen: There is nothing different here between .NET versions, none of them, not even a hypothetical .NET 6. Please change to `.net` unless you can provide proof.

Comment: @leppie I didn't even know there was a version 5...  Has ANYTHING related to my question ever changed from .Net1 to .Net4.6.1?  Was the params and ref keywords available in .Net1?  The reason for using the specific tag .net-4.0 is to always stay within the scope of the 4.0 framework.  If someone has a work around or even a "Yes it's possible" answer in the future it would not apply here.

Comment: @ArvoBowen: It is not possible in any current .NET.

Comment: @leppie I didn't ask if it is currently possible in any version of .NET.  But you on the other hand are telling me it will NEVER be available in any future version of .Net framework as if you can see the future.

Comment: @ArvoBowen: You are asking if it will ever be available in .NET 4 in the future. The answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So the simple answer is no, you can´t have a method return an infinite number of references.**

What should be the benefit on such a feature? Obvioulsy you want a method that can change **any** object no matter where it comes from nor who is using it any more. This hardly is a break on the [Single-Responsibility-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of a class, making it a [God-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

What you can do however is create the instances within an enumeration:

```
private bool Test(object[] differentStructures)
{
    differentStructures[0] = someOtherRessource;
    differentStructures[1] = anotherDifferentRessource
    differentStructures[2] = thirdDifferentRessource
}
```

And call it like:

```
var tests = new[] {
    default(TestStructOne),
    default(TestStructTwo),
    default(TestStructOne)
}
Test(tests);
```

Which will lead to the following:

```
tests[0] = someOtherRessource;
tests[1] = anotherDifferentRessource
tests[2] = thirdDifferentRessource
```

Comment: Thanks, this does explain the IEnumerable method but does not help me in the way I'm using the Test() function.  In my example (though simple) is not representing the intention of the function.  I wanted to keep the question simple to get a simple answer (which I did and that's why I will accept your answer if you bold the line "So the simple answer...")  I don't think it is anything like a "god object" though...  My intent was to take a bunch of objects in and write them to a byte array.  Like I said, I can do that already.  Just wanted to make it quicker/simpler.