# How passing multiple parameters as "params" but referenced in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, ref

I'm looking if there's a way to pass any number of parameters with "params" but referenced in C#

I have a function that return an string, that string is modified inside this function, is something like this:

```
Main:
var myWord = FormatWord(myWord);

funct:
public string FormatWord(string myWord)
{
    // do something
}
```

for now, there's a function that just receive 1 parameter, but in the future could be more than one parameter and I don't want to use this function to every single string and assign the returned value, I was thinking that an easy way to solve this should be send any number of string referenced parameters and do the same logic for each string, looking something like this:

```
Main:
FormatWord(myWord1, myWord2, myWord3);

funct:
public void FormatWord(ref params string[] words)
{
    // do something
}
```

and then doesn't matter how many string words you pass as parameter, same logic will apply for them.

The problem is you can't do this due you will get this:

```
A parameter cannot have all the specified modifiers; there are too many modifiers on the parameter
```

There's any way to do what I want?

Comment: Can you explain why you're wanting to use `ref`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't mix and match `params` and `ref`; it would make no sense.  You can pass an array of strings in (whether explicitly, or using `params`) and you can return an array.  That's probably what you want to do (or, better still, return an `IEnumerable<string>`)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776347/43846)

Comment: You could write multiple overloads of `FormatWord` that take up to N parameters.

Comment: hi @Jacob
I want to pass multiple string values referenced, doesn't matter if it just 1 or 40, for those string will be applied the same logic, but something that I have a concern is, imagine in the future have 40 strings, then use this function to assign the returned value to each one, it would be 40 lines of code, instead of that, would like to pass every single referenced string in that function and just fill the value inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that "ref" needs to be mentioned in the call and not just in the declaration.  As mentioned in the comments, this doesn't really make sense to combine both "ref" and "params" in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an array or list to store all your string variables, then pass it into your method?

For example:

```
Main:
var words = new List<string>() ;
words.add(myWord1);
words.add(myWord2);
words.add(myWord3);
FormatWord(words);

funct:
public void FormatWord(List<string> myWordList)
{
    // do something
}
```