# Is there a way to create a Pass-By-Reference list of managed-type variables?

Tags: c#, data-structures, pass-by-reference

edit; Based on responses, I may have been unclear in my final goal. I've updated the last section.

**Situation**

I have a number of variables which I need to perform the same operation on. In this case, they are `strings`, and can at the point we reach this code have the value `null`, `""`, `"Blank"`, or they could already have an assigned other value that I want to keep.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyVar1) || "Blank".Equals(MyVar1))
    MyVar1 = null;
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyVar2) || "Blank".Equals(MyVar2))
    MyVar2 = null;
...
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyVar10) || "Blank".Equals(MyVar10))
    MyVar10 = null;
```

Being a programmer that wants to keep my code clean and this block drives me mad, I'm looking for a way to create a list of these variables, and perform this same `if` statement + null assignment on each.

For an example, here's what I'd like to do:

```
MyVar1 = "Blank";
DreamDataStructure varList = new DreamDataStructure() { MyVar1, MyVar2, ..., MyVar10 };
foreach(ref string MyVar in varList)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyVar) || "Blank".Equals(MyVar))
        MyVar = null;
}
Console.WriteLine(MyVar1); //Should now be null
```

**What Doesn't Work**

1) Because my variables are `strings`, I can't do something like this.

```
var myListOfVariables = new[] { &MyVar1, &MyVar2, ..., &MyVar10 };
```

If I could, I'd be able to `foreach` over them as expected. Because `string` is a managed type though, it cannot be passed by reference like this.

2) Similarly, if I just made a `List<string>` of the variables, they would be passed by value and wouldn't help my case.

3) These variables can't be wrapped in an outer object type, as they need to be used as strings in a large number of places in a legacy application. Assume that it would be too large an effort to change how they're used in every location.

**Question**

Is there a way to iterate over `string` (or other managed type) variables in a pass-by-reference way that will allow me to put the entire operation inside of a loop and reduce the duplication of code that's happening here?

The goal here is that I can use the **original variables** later on in my code with the updated values. MyVar1, etc, are referenced later on already by legacy code which expects them to be `null` or have an actual value.

Comment: *"These variables can't be wrapped in an outer object type, as they need to be used as strings in a large number of places in a legacy application."* Would you accept an outer object type that is used *just* for this purpose, where the outer object type sets the variables?

Comment: @JoeSewell If you mean an object/method/etc that can do this manipulation, that's totally fine, as long as MyVar1 et al remain `strings` and are updated as expected.

Comment: Now I understand what you're trying to do. `DreamDataStructure` makes it look like these are already properties of a class, but they're not. They're just variables. If you modify your code so that these variables are properties of a class, this becomes easy. But if you can't - all you have are individual variables and you're stuck with that - then you can only modify them one at a time. There's just no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think what you want to do is possible. Please see this question: [Interesting "params of ref" feature, any workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776020/interesting-params-of-ref-feature-any-workarounds)

The only thing I can suggest (which I know doesn't answer your question) is creating a method to avoid duplication of your conditional logic:

```cs
void Convert(ref string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || "Blank".Equals(text))
    {
        text = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very interesting link, and may very well show that this isn't possible. I'll give it a read and accept this answer if that appears to be the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Now I get what you're trying to do. You have a bunch of variables, and you want to perform some sort of bulk operation on them without changing anything else. Putting them in a class isn't an option.

In that case you're really stuck operating on them one at a time. There are ways to shorten it, but you're pretty much stuck with the repetition.

I'd

- create a `string SanitizeString(string input)` function
- type `x = SanitizeString(x);` once for each variable
- copy and paste the variable names to replace `x`.

It's lame, but that's about all there is.

---

Perhaps this would be a better approach. It ensures that the values are always sanitized. Otherwise you can't easily tell whether the values have been sanitized or not:

```
public class MyValues
{
    private string _value1;
    private string _value2;
    private string _value3;

    public string Value1
    {
        get { return _value1; }
        set { _value1 = Sanitize(value); }
    }

    // repeat for other values

    private string Sanitize(string input) =>
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || string.Equals("Blank", input) ? null : input;
}
```

That's one option. Another is to sanitize the inputs earlier. But ideally we want to ensure that a given class is always in a valid state. We wouldn't want to have an instance of a class whether the values may or may not be valid. It's better to ensure that they are always valid.

`ref` doesn't really factor into it. We don't need to use it often, if ever. With a value type or `string` we can just return a new value from a function.

If we're passing a reference type and we want to make changes to it (like setting its properties, adding items to a list) then we're already passing a reference and we don't need to specify `ref`.

I'd try to write methods first without using `ref` and only use it if you need to. You probably never will because you'll succeed at whatever you're trying to do without using `ref`.

---

Your comment mentioned that this is a legacy app and it's preferable not to modify the existing class. That leaves one more option - reflection. Not my favorite, but when you say "legacy app" I feel your pain. In that case you could do this:

```
public static class StringSanitizer
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>> _stringProperties = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>>();

    public static void SanitizeStringProperties<T>(T input) where T : class
    {
        if (!_stringProperties.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _stringProperties.Add(typeof(T), GetStringProperties(typeof(T)));
        }

        foreach (var property in _stringProperties[typeof(T)])
        {
            property.SetValue(input, Sanitize((string)property.GetValue(input)));
        }
    }

    private static string Sanitize(string input)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || string.Equals("Blank", input) ? null : input;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetStringProperties(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property.CanRead && property.CanWrite);
    }
}
```

This will take an object, find its string properties, and sanitize them. It will store the string properties in a dictionary by type so that once it has discovered the string properties for a given type it won't have to do it again.

```
StringSanitizer.SanitizeStringProperties(someObject);
```

Comment: #3 on "what doesnt work" explains my issue with this approach. This is a legacy application, the work it would take to replace how MyVar1, etc, are used downstream isn't feasible. Believe me, I'd love to have an approach that didn't rely on string parsing.

Comment: I provided a second option, but my first one doesn't affect existing code that uses this class. That's actually the point. Code that reads the properties doesn't change. Code that sets the properties doesn't change either. The class itself sanitizes the properties when they are set.

Comment: The other area of the application still have calls like `displayText = MyVar1 ?? 0`, which is what causes the issue. I still need MyVar to contain either null or valid text, I can't go and replace MyVar1 with MyNewTypeVar1 or MyValues.Value1. The reflection approach is interesting, but I'll have to do some research in to see if I can have it sanitize every string variable, or if it has to only do a subset. It is a possible answer to my specific scenario, but I've love a more generalized approach if possible for the future.

Comment: I'm realizing that I still didn't understand the question. What you're describing is a perfect example of why we use classes. If all you have are a bunch of variables, then the only way to operate on them is one at a time. Having a class with properties is what enables you to perform the sort of operation you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function instead of passing references, which would also be more readable.

```
string Validate(string inputString)
{
   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) || "Blank".Equals(inputString) ? null : inputString;
}

<...>
 MyVar1 = Validate(MyVar1);
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a scalable solution. If there were 100 variables, I'd still need to call validate for each one (which is what I want to avoid)

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use a string[] and get the changes back to the caller method like this.

```
public Main()
{
    var myVar1 = "Blank";
    var myVar2 = "";
    string myVar3 = null;
    var myVar4 = "";
    string[] dreamDataStructure = new string[] { myVar1, myVar2, myVar3, myVar4 };
}

private void ProcessStrings(string[] list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(list[i]) || "Blank".Equals(list[i]))
            list[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the original variables to the updated, not the strings in the array.